# Rails can't import JavaScript file in production

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to implement the [JsQRScanner](https://github.com/jbialobr/JsQRScanner) in my Rails app  and am running into a problem.

The scanner works in development but not in production. The main file imports the other JavaScript files relative to its location. In development this isn't a problem because all the files are located in the same folder. In production however, when Rails compiles the assets, the main JsQRScanner file tries to import its dependencies based on the location of the application.js file. This leads to this error:

```
GET https://mywebsite.ca/en/dummy/transactions/E6E6E3F2A803616D0A10675BBD03B058.cache.js  404 not found
```

This might not be best practice, but, for now, I want to add that JavaScript file to that location, which is the location of the HTML views file. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: It's because "the main JsQRScanner file" becomes part of the compiled application.js.

Comment: Yes you're right, I knew that was the problem but for whatever reason did not know how to solve it. I think I had just been staring at it for too long...

Ended up putting the js code in the public folder and importing it inline from there. I can probably just do the same from the assets file but for now it works and I'm stepping away.

Comment: I have the exact same problem but with Sails.js - it also bundles all .js files in a single js file in production. How did you solve it? Excluded the jsqrscanner from bundling?

Comment: @Suisse I added the file to my public folder and excluded it from the bundle. This way I could reference it in production. I think this allows anyone to see the file though so if sails.js contains sensitive data I would try to find another way.

Comment: @evanshabsove how do you exclude that file from bundle in sails.js? and with "public" you just mean the asset folder? I can't get it to work

Comment: @Suisse what do you mean by this sails.js file? Are you importing everything into your application.js file? In my project I specify every file I am importing to avoid confusion. As for the public folder there should be one in the root directory of your project so "project_name/public". Then add a folder for example "project_name/public/sails" put the file in there and reference that in your view.

Comment: By Sails.js I mean the Node.js Framework called "Sails.js" (not ruby on rails) - thx I solved it like this: I made 2 copies of that E6E6E3F2A803616D0A10675BBD03B058.cache.js file - one of them is in the same folder as the other qrScanner js files, so that it can be found - the other one is in the /assets folder; after that I added a new route in the route.js file which is pointing from /users/show (this is the endpoint where I need the qrScanner) to /assets/E6E6E3F2A803616D0A10675BBD03B058.cache.js - and now it works... took me weeks to figure out!